# Split Excel sheets to multiple Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with multiple Sheets. I would like to split it into separate files, with 3 sheets per file.

I created a new WorkBook as follows:

```
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
With NewBook
     .Title = "File1"
     .Subject = "File1"
     .SaveAs FileName:="File1.xls"
End With
```

How can I copy sheets from one to another?

Comment: Use ``ActiveSheet.SaveAs`` method instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will

- split you workbook into new workbooks of batches of 3 sheets at a time,
- save them as new files with the naming below
- close them

> File1 (first 3 sheets)
>   File4 (sheets 4-6)
>   File7 (sheets 7-9)

The code will "pad" out the Excel file with extra sheets to keep to the 3 sheet split mutiple.

Note that you can create a new Workbook using `.Copy` - no need to use `Workbooks.Add`

**`Code to be run from the Workbook to be split`**

```
Sub BatchThree()
    Dim lngSht As Long
    Dim lngShtAdd As Long
    Dim lngShts As Long
    Dim bSht As Boolean
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
    lngSht = 1

    'pad extra sheets
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count Mod 3 <> 0 Then
        bSht = True
        lngShts = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count Mod 3
        For lngShtAdd = 3 To (lngShts + 1) Step -1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Next
    End If

    Do While lngSht + 2 <= ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        Sheets(Array(lngSht, lngSht + 1, lngSht + 2)).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "/File" & lngSht
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        lngSht = lngSht + 3
    Loop

    'remove extra sheets
    If bSht Then
     For lngShtAdd = 3 To (lngShts + 1) Step -1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Delete
        Next
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The base syntax to make a copy (if that is your question):

```
Sub Make_Copy()
Thisworkbook.Sheets(1).Copy _
   after:=SomeWorkbook.Sheets(1)
End Sub
```

Next to copy, naturally you can also move sheets. You can copy before instead of after and change the name of the sheet.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question - wants to split a file into multiple workbooks with "3 sheets per file"

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood... I read the last phrase how can I make a copy? And in the code provided he creates a new workbook...